# Safety flying in Dubai air space

Tags: air-travel, safety, dubai, event-based-effects

How safe is flying through Dubai air space considering the current unrest between the USA and Iran?
We are booked through to UK in July.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly as safe as it ever was. If there were an unacceptably higher risk, the airline would take measures to mitigate the risk, or stop flying in the risky area(s). They absolutely do not want another [MH17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malaysia_Airlines_Flight_17).

Answer (score 1):

Currently it looks like Emirates flights are overflying Iraq, avoiding both Iran and Syria. For example, this flight track from EK164 taken a few minutes ago.

AFAIK there are no particular safety concerns flying within the UAE, so I presume you meant flights to/from UAE.

[image: EK164 from Flight Aware 2019/05/21]

Comment: A few Emirates flights towards Europe do fly over Iran instead of Iraq, with no clear pattern to which. Right now on Flightradar24, I see EK91 (A380 to Milan) EK85 (A380 to Zurich), EK163 (B777 to Dublin), EK181 (B777 to Brussels) over Iran. [At the same time there's a column of nine Emirates A380s in progress north over Iraq, so it looks like _most_ go that way].